# PHP Default Timezone Config

Tags: php

I noticed today that the date reported by PHP is wrong.

When I went into the PHP file to try to change the timezone, I get a big ugly warning saying it is mandatory to set the timezone.

I get no error when the timezone is set to UTC but the date is wrong.

Every other value besides UTC throws the error.

What is this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"
```

Put that in your php.ini file with the approrpriate timezone from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), and then restart your HTTP server.

If you don't want to set it globally, but want to set it on a script-by-script basis, use this code on each page where a date/time function is used:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Like the global timezone setting, pick your timezone from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).